# Text causing div to increase in size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a landing page, with an image with text over it.

I have the div that contains the text as a child div to the image div, and the image uses viewport height to fill the whole screen, however as soon as I insert text in the centered child div, for some reason the image gets resized in height, and there's uneeded scrolling space. I have tried different display types, and everything.

I've made an example, one with the div that shows the text and one without

With text and extra scrolling space: http://jsfiddle.net/g7ch1p0j/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ekchö</title>
  <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div id="header_bg">
  <div class="fluid_controller">
   <div id="header_text">Ekchö</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lander">
  </div>
  <div class="fluid_controller">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Without text and no scrolling space between the image and content below it: http://jsfiddle.net/sctcebmf/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ekchö</title>
  <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div id="header_bg">
  <div class="fluid_controller">
   <div id="header_text">Ekchö</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="lander">
  </div>
  <div class="fluid_controller">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see the text moving upwards a little bit (grab the scrollwheel and drag it down slowly) before you see the end of the image (black box) and that's because of the extra issue. This does not appear in the second example.

Comment: The div did not increase in size. It has the same size in both cases (458px). What happened is that the #lander div was pushed down a bit in the second case. I'm investigating it further to see if I can find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got your fiddle working as expected by changing `#lander_meta`'s position to `absolute`, adding `width:100%` and making its `p` tags `text-align: center`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7ch1p0j/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed everything. :)